# How can I simulate Android OS killing off an Activity due to low system resources for testing

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-lifecycle, onresume

When the user leaves an activity, Android moves it to the recent apps. When Android needs more memory, it "kills" the app - unloads all Activity objects and will no longer exist. The user can still click on the app in the recent apps which starts the activity where the user left it. This often causes nullPointerException. We can prevent it by saving data with SharedPreferences, database or savedInstanceState.

How can I test whether I implemented data saving correctly without waiting on Android to unload objects of activity? i.e. how can I force Android to "kill" my activity?

Comment: You can force stop the app in the Active Applications like in [this picture](http://www.ekoob.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/close-active-applications-android.png) and then go back to it manually. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @Vucko not really, this indeed does unload objects of activity, but when clicking on the app in the recents, the Android starts default activity instead of resuming the old one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a section called `Apps` in the `Developer options`. Make sure `Do not keep activities` is on, it'll allow you to test this behavior. Just don't forget to turn it off when you're done or you will be debugging weird lifecycle behavior in your app later.

Answer (score 1):

Just rotate your device, it will recreate the activity again. So you will be able to simulate your issue. But to add to this, kindly save the state of the variable you are getting null pointer exception in "OnSaveInstance" and then restore it in "OnRestoreInstance". This will solve your issue.

Make sure any of the below property is not added for your activity.

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

`or`

```
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"  or portrait is not set.
```

Because if that is the case it will not recreate the activity when the device is rotated.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: +1. this is helpful, thanks, but C0D3LIC1OU5's answer is better for my purposes so I will accepts his one.